# Compile errors in ksmedia.h (in direct X sdk)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, directx, header-files

I was given a C++ project that I have to work on that compiles and works on a different computer.  It uses the Direct X SDK.  I have not modified anything about the project.  However, when I try to compile the project in Visual Studio 2008, I get a number of compile errors in ksmedia.h.  I searched and couldn't find any others with the same errors that I am getting and a valid solution.  They are as follows:

```
1>path\Include\ksmedia.h(453) : error C2332: 'struct' : missing tag name
1>path\Include\ksmedia.h(453) : error C2011: '<unnamed-tag>' : 'enum' type redefinition
1>        path\BaseClasses\wxdebug.h(58) : see declaration of '<unnamed-tag>'
1>path\Include\ksmedia.h(453) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__uuidof'
1>path\Include\ksmedia.h(453) : error C2059: syntax error : '__uuidof'
1>path\Include\ksmedia.h(547) : error C2332: 'struct' : missing tag name
1>path\Include\ksmedia.h(547) : error C2011: '<unnamed-tag>' : 'enum' type redefinition
1>        path\BaseClasses\wxdebug.h(58) : see declaration of '<unnamed-tag>'
1>\Include\ksmedia.h(547) : error C3121: cannot change GUID for class '<unnamed-tag>'
1>        path\BaseClasses\wxdebug.h(58) : see declaration of '<unnamed-tag>'
1>path\Include\ksmedia.h(547) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__uuidof'
1>path\Include\ksmedia.h(547) : error C2059: syntax error : '__uuidof'
1>path\Include\ksmedia.h(553) : error C2332: 'struct' : missing tag name
1>path\Include\ksmedia.h(553) : error C2011: '<unnamed-tag>' : 'enum' type redefinition
1>        path\BaseClasses\wxdebug.h(58) : see declaration of '<unnamed-tag>'
1>path\Include\ksmedia.h(553) : error C3121: cannot change GUID for class '<unnamed-tag>'
1>        path\BaseClasses\wxdebug.h(58) : see declaration of '<unnamed-tag>'
1>path\Include\ksmedia.h(553) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__uuidof'
1>path\Include\ksmedia.h(553) : error C2059: syntax error : '__uuidof'
```

Any knowledge on what is causing these errors or what I can do to fix them would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I was using an old version of the ksmedia.h file.  I have changed my copy to [ksmedia.h](http://www.koders.com/c/fidD0EEC74AA9666F0514A67A906C14173ED287023A.aspx) and updated the error message to reflect the change.  Also, the Windows and DirectX SDK versions are the same.  However, the computer it compiles on is 32-bit and the one it won't is 64-bit.

Comment: you should give the link to the file ksmedia.h or atleast paste the lines 549, 643 649 etc... it is not `easy` to read the compiler error and speculate what is going on in the code

Comment: Are you compiling for the same target platform on both systems or are you compiling for 32-bit on the 32-bit system and for 64-bit on the 64-bit system?  If the latter, have you tried compiling for a 64-bit target on the 32-bit system?

Comment: I was compiling it on a 64-bit system for a 64-bit system while the working machine is a 32-bit system and was compiling for a 32-bit system.  I have switched to a 32-bit system and everything works now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Since the project compiles on one computer but not on another you're obviously looking for some difference between the two.

One possibility is that the two systems have different versions of the DirectX SDK installed. Not a very likely possibility perhaps but worth checking if only to eliminate it from consideration.

Another possibility is that the two systems have different versions of some other SDK installed.

A third possibility is that the two copies of Visual Studio are configured to search the include folders of the various SDKs in different orders.  That can cause problems when the definition for some type or macro comes from one header file on one system and a completely different header file on the other system.

Go to Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | VC++ Directories on the system where compiles are successful.  Set "Show directories for" to "Include files" and then take note of the list of folders shown, including the order of that list.

Now do the same on the second system where the compile is failing and compare the two lists.  The two lists might not be identical.  One system might have an SDK installed that the other system does not; the two systems might have the same SDK installed in different places.  Still, the *intent* of the lists should be the same.

If the DirectX SDK entry in the good system's list appears before the Windows SDK entry then the two entries in the bad system's list should appear in the same order too.  You'll have to use your best judgement about entries that appear in one list but not the other - or experiment carefully (but remember changing that list could affect any build performed by that copy of Visual Studio).